# How to set an ngb-accordion to expand in Angular

Tags: html, angular, frontend, accordion, panel

I currently have ngb-accordions set to a number of panels. By default the panels are closed and I am using a custom function to expand them when clicked. I would like to know how to set an accordion to be expanded by default if the category name is select.

```
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <ngb-accordion #filterAccordion [animation]="false" (click)="heightChanged()"#acc="ngbAccordion" [activeIds]="activeIds">
        <ngb-panel *ngFor="let filterCategory of filterCategories | filterCategory | keyvalue : returnZero ;let i= index" id="panel-{{i}}">
            <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
              <button class="header-btn" (click)="heightChanged()">
                <span>{{filterCategory.value.translationId | translate}}</span>
              </button>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent *ngIf="filterCategory.value.filterParameters.length > 0">
              <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-md-2" *ngFor="let filter of filterCategory.value.filterParameters | keyvalue">
                  <app-filter-parameters *ngIf="filterCategory.key.toString() !== 'select'"
                                         [(filterParameterValue)]="filter.value.value"
                                         [filterParameterName]="filter.value.key"
                                         [dsaComponent]="'dashboardFilter'"
                                         (applyFilters)="apply()">
                  </app-filter-parameters>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-2" *ngIf="filterCategory.key.toString() === 'select'">
                  <app-date-picker
                    [filterParameters]="filterCategory.value.filterParameters"
                    [dsaComponent]="'dashboardFilter'"
                    (updateTimeframe)="this.updateFilter($event)">
                  </app-date-picker>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
          </ngb-panel>
      </ngb-accordion>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set same ID for all ngb-panels:

```
<ngb-accordion [activeIds]="activeIds"></ngb-accordion>

// For example
this.activeIds = ['UNIQ_ID','UNIQ_ID','UNIQ_ID'];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? How would I cater for the ngif statement?

Answer (score 1):

Since this still comes up as top search for `"ngbaccordion open default"`, thought i should include some updated information,

With the updates to the new attribute based `ngbAccordion`, ie:

```
<ngb-accordion>
```

now becomes:

```
<div ngbAccordion>
```

we can now expand using `collapsed` attribute on `ngbAccordionItem` to set open by default, ie:

```
<div ngbAccordionItem [collapsed]="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `activeIds` to open panels initially.

You added `id="panel-{{i}}"` to each panel. So for example, if first panel should be opened by default, you should initialize `activeIds="panel-0"`:

```html
<ngb-accordion #filterAccordion [animation]="false" (click)="heightChanged()"#acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="panel-0">
```

Comment: Could you add to my code please? As I think that will just make them stay open once clicked.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: Sadly does not work. The panel id is only being added after the ngfor loop.